# The difference between func and &func in memmory

Tags: c, memory

I have a simple question.
I have this code :

```
int foo();
int main (int argc, char** argv){
printf("- foo: %p\n",foo);
printf("- foo: %p\n",&foo);
}
```

I noticed both lines print a very low address (text segment), but I don't understand the difference between the lines.

Comment: There is none, a function *decays* to a pointer to itself naturally, so `foo` will be the same as `&foo`.

Comment: functions and arrays without parentheses have no other meaning.than possessing &